# Joint Convexity of weighted norm of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis

Let $\mathbf{a}$ be a vector with positive entries and $\mathbf{b}$ be a complex vector, then is the following function joint convex on $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$?
$$\sum_{m=1}^{M} a_m |b_m|^2.$$

Comment: Kind of strange. Just restrict to a suitable convex subset of the domain. (Is $x\mapsto x(1-x)^2$ convex on $(0,1)$?)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, you are right, this is not joint convex.